# Visual Studio -- get comment tokens of Task list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, envdte

I'm trying to get a list of all comment tokens which I have defined on the task list in VS2015.

I'm getting the `TaskList` and I'm able to see all comment tokens like TODO, HACK, etc. in the debugger - but I can't find a way to access them programatically.

```
DTE2 dte = (DTE2)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE));           
TaskList tl = dte.ToolWindows.TaskList;

In Debugger ----------------------------------------------------------------------
TaskList tl
  --    CommentTokens   Count = 4 
         --    [0] {Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorListPkg.Shims.CommentTaskToken}     
               --    IsDefault  true    bool
               --    Priority   Normal  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.CommentTaskPriority
               --    Text       "TODO"  string
         --    [1] {Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorListPkg.Shims.CommentTaskToken}   
               ...
```

`TaskList.TaskItems` only returns the items that are displayed in the VS-TaskList-Window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [`TaskList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/envdte.tasklist.aspx) is only an interface, you have to unwrap it's implementation to get the `CommentTokens` property. Can't find any reference for the target type, but did you try to select `CommentTokens` or `TaskList` in Debug window and add them to Watch? You can find a real type for them, and after that cast the `dte.ToolWindows.TaskList` to the right one. After that you'll be able to get the `CommentTokens` collection.

Suggested edit was rejected, so I add the information by myself:

Edit: The solution is to create a `dymanic` variable, assign it with `dte.ToolWindows.TaskList` and get the `CommentTokens` property.

```
DTE2 dte = (DTE2)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE));
TaskList tl = dte.ToolWindows.TaskList;
dynamic commentTokens = ((dynamic)tl).CommentTokens;

// getting the token from the TaskList
foreach(dynamic token in commentTokens) {
    tokens.Add(token.Text);
}
```

Comment: I can see in the debugger that the cast I'm looking for is: ((Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorListPkg.Shims.TaskList)tl).CommentTokens but I cant find any reference to ErrorListPkg

Comment: [`TaskList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.tasklist.aspx) interface is located into [`EnvDTE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.aspx) namespace, which is for internal use only. I think that only some reflection could help you to get this information.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help... But this gets to complicated for me -  there is too much i don't know anything about.

Comment: You can try to create `dymanic` variable, assign it with `dte.ToolWindows.TaskList` and try out to get `CommentTokens` property. May be this could help

Comment: Yes you are right - this does the trick.
   
     `DTE2 dte = (DTE2)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE));

     TaskList tl = dte.ToolWindows.TaskList;
     dynamic commentTokens = tl.GetType().GetProperty("CommentTokens").GetValue(tl);

  // getting the token from the TaskList
  foreach(dynamic token in commentTokens) {
        tokens.Add(token.Text);
  }`

Thank you :)

Comment: I've added your edit to my answer. You can answer your own question if you found a solution - this is a completely normal here :) Good Luck with your projects!

Comment: Haha okay :) Thank you